# Move the next button after dropdown from the first button

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to do is: when I click on one of the buttons, the paragraph area shows (as it is now). However, I want the next button / div (and the rest of the page below it) to move downwards. To get it simple: when I click on the button, the box shows, while moving the rest of the buttons downwards, so the paragraph area doesn't overlap the others.

I'm sorry for the bad English... 
I hope you guys understand what I mean.
( Btw I don't want a frameworks or Jquery, just plain languages ;) )

I have got the following code:

```js
function dropDownOne() {
    document.getElementById("dropdownone").classList.toggle("show");
}

function dropDownTwo() {
    document.getElementById("dropdowntwo").classList.toggle("show");
}

function dropDownThree() {
    document.getElementById("dropdownthree").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if(!event.target.matches('.dropdownbtn')) {

        let dropDowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        for (var i = 0; i < dropDowns.length; i++) {
            let openDropDown = dropDowns[i];
            if (openDropDown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropDown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.dropdownbtn {
    border: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -moz-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -ms-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -o-transition-duration: 300ms;
    transition-duration: 300ms;
}

.dropdownbtn:hover, .dropdownbtn:focus {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -moz-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -ms-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -o-transition-duration: 300ms;
    transition-duration: 300ms;
}

.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 80vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
}

.show {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="dropDownOne()" class="dropdownbtn">Who am I?</button>
            <div id="dropdownone" class="dropdown-content">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab commodi consequuntur delectus deleniti
                    dignissimos ea eveniet excepturi id impedit, maiores maxime obcaecati officiis quaerat, quam
                    recusandae rem sunt, temporibus velit.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="dropDownTwo()" class="dropdownbtn">What are your skills?</button>
            <div id="dropdowntwo" class="dropdown-content">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab commodi consequuntur delectus deleniti
                    dignissimos ea eveniet excepturi id impedit, maiores maxime obcaecati officiis quaerat, quam
                    recusandae rem sunt, temporibus velit.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="dropDownThree()" class="dropdownbtn">Who am I?</button>
            <div id="dropdownthree" class="dropdown-content">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab commodi consequuntur delectus deleniti
                    dignissimos ea eveniet excepturi id impedit, maiores maxime obcaecati officiis quaerat, quam
                    recusandae rem sunt, temporibus velit.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your problem was you were using `position : absolute;` on your `dropdown-content` class, because it has an absolute position it means that the element will take its position regardless of any other elements, which is why your other elements didn't move.

To fix this I changed it to `position: relative;` so other elements will take it's position into account.

I also removed `margin-bottom: 200px;` in the `show` class as this was leaving large gaps between each if your elements.

Here is the edited code in a snippet:

```js
function dropDownOne() {
    document.getElementById("dropdownone").classList.toggle("show");
}

function dropDownTwo() {
    document.getElementById("dropdowntwo").classList.toggle("show");
}

function dropDownThree() {
    document.getElementById("dropdownthree").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if(!event.target.matches('.dropdownbtn')) {

        let dropDowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        for (var i = 0; i < dropDowns.length; i++) {
            let openDropDown = dropDowns[i];
            if (openDropDown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropDown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.dropdownbtn {
    border: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -moz-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -ms-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -o-transition-duration: 300ms;
    transition-duration: 300ms;
}

.dropdownbtn:hover, .dropdownbtn:focus {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -moz-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -ms-transition-duration: 300ms;
    -o-transition-duration: 300ms;
    transition-duration: 300ms;
}

.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 80vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="dropDownOne()" class="dropdownbtn">Who am I?</button>
            <div id="dropdownone" class="dropdown-content">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab commodi consequuntur delectus deleniti
                    dignissimos ea eveniet excepturi id impedit, maiores maxime obcaecati officiis quaerat, quam
                    recusandae rem sunt, temporibus velit.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="dropDownTwo()" class="dropdownbtn">What are your skills?</button>
            <div id="dropdowntwo" class="dropdown-content">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab commodi consequuntur delectus deleniti
                    dignissimos ea eveniet excepturi id impedit, maiores maxime obcaecati officiis quaerat, quam
                    recusandae rem sunt, temporibus velit.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="dropDownThree()" class="dropdownbtn">Who am I?</button>
            <div id="dropdownthree" class="dropdown-content">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab commodi consequuntur delectus deleniti
                    dignissimos ea eveniet excepturi id impedit, maiores maxime obcaecati officiis quaerat, quam
                    recusandae rem sunt, temporibus velit.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```